# Change sender's cornerRadius

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My code:

```
-(void)buttonTap:(id)sender {
    UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    [[sender layer] setCornerRadius:15.0f]; //nothing happens
    myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f; //nothing happens
    myButton.hidden = YES; //works fine
}
```

How can I change cornerRadius of sender?

Comment: What does 'not working' mean? Compiler error? Runtime error? Nothing happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would try to add `button.clipsToBounds = YES`. It may be that the `UIButton` control uses subviews which ignore the property `cornerRadius`.